# Unable to access Jekyll posts' custom variables when accessed via the site.categories

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In one of my posts I added this custom variable:

```
exclude-from-indexes: true
```

In the layout for the category this post appears in, I have:

```
{% for post in site.categories[page.category] %}
  {% if post.exclude-from-indexes!=true %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, the page is still included.

If I add:

```
{{ post.exclude-from-indexes }}
```

The variable is not shown.

I have tried different key names, but this doesn't appear to work. If I do:

```
{{ post | inspect }}
```

The key is not shown.

Am I accessing or declaring the custom variables in the wrong way? Or am I accessing some strange type of "post" that doesn't have the custom variables?

I noticed in another page, if I do:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {{ post.exclude-from-indexes }}
{% endfor %}
```

The variable *is* shown. So I think it's something to do with the data stored in `site.categories[page.category]`...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the keyname. Using:

```
excludefromindexes=true
```

Fixes it.